# Jerarquia de los archivos .css

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, md-bootstrap

Contexto: Inicie un proyecto con bootstrap-5 pero a este framework le falta el search-select por lo que compre un paquete de componentes de MDB que trae uno que funciona con bootestrap-5, basicamente solo era relacionar dos archivos, mdb.css y mdb.js. Como es un paquete... trae todos los componentes y solo necesito el search-select, despues de algunos ajustes logre que el search-select funcionara y que se pareciera a los otros elementos, pero realmente todos los componentes de bootstrap-5 se dañaron de inmediato en tamaño, color, comportamiento y apariencia.

los link quedaron asi:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mdb.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Esperaba se ejecutaran las referencias a clases, nombres y demas de `mdb.css` que no estan en `bootstrap.css` y de ahi en adelante se ejecuten las de `bootstrap.css` que tambien estan en `mdb.css`, pero eso no paso.

Existe alguna Jerarquia de los archivos .css que funcione como lo esperaba?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Muy bien `bootstrap.css` esta por encima de `mdb.css` ya que primero el navegador primero lee lo que esta primero pero luego si hay lo mismo abajo el lo reemplaza con lo de abajo.

De esta manera sale que tu arreglas todo en el `mdb.css` y luego el `bootstrap.css` lo vuelve a dañar.

La solucion es cambiar de lugares los archivos css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mdb.css" />
```

O tambien puedes intentar en lugar de `bootstrap.css` conectar `bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Decidi no usar mdb, me ha dado muchos problemas, encontre este https://www.webslesson.info/2022/02/bootstrap-5-select-dropdown-with-search-box-using-vanilla-javascript-php-mysql.html y lo estoy arreglando. Gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: Ok, pero si tu pregunta esta resuelta cierrela o si te sirvio para algo mi respuesta apruebala con dar clic en el icono del visto al lado izquierdo de la respuesta